# "I need to dig deeper in hard disk" VS "I need to dig deeper in the hard disk"?

Tags: articles, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> 1. I need to dig deeper in hard disk

or

> 2. I need to dig deeper in the hard disk.

Which one is right?

Is hard disk uncountable?

Is hard disk uncountable noun in the first sentence if the sentence is right?

Does the word hard disk countable in the second sentence ?

Comment: You may have several hard disks inside your computer's tower. So, you need a definite article there, if you are talking about a specific disk that needs further investigations!

Comment: I agree. "Deeper in hard disk" doesn't mean anything.